# Sorting data in MemoryStore (or any arbitrary data array)

Tags: javascript, sorting, dojo

Does Dojo hat any utilities for sotring the data within `MemoryStore`, or optionally, within any data collection?

I'd need **all** data from the `MemoryStore`, but sorted by single evt. more columns. Something like `Collections.sort` in Java...

I'd expect Store to have `sort` function, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dojo/store` API](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store.html) allows sorting data at query time only, as far as I know. For example:

```
var store = new Memory({
    data: [{
        "firstName": "Bird",
        "name": "Schultz"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Brittany",
        "name": "Berg"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Haley",
        "name": "Good"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Randolph",
        "name": "Phillips"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Bernard",
        "name": "Small"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Leslie",
        "name": "Wynn"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Mercado",
        "name": "Singleton"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Esmeralda",
        "name": "Huber"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Juanita",
        "name": "Saunders"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Beverly",
        "name": "Clemons"
    }]
});

console.log("Alphabetically by first name:");
store.query({}, {
    sort: [{
        attribute: "firstName",
        descending: false
    }]
}).forEach(function(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.name);
});
```

You can provide multiple sort attributes as well.

Full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9HtT3/

Answer (score 1):

When we sort our Data, we do this actual before the Items are stored. We take the filtered Values that are saved in an array and use array.sort()and called inside a function SortByName or SortByNumbers

looks like this:

```
function streetsToCombobox(results){

    var adress;
    var values = [];
    var testVals={};

    var features = results.features;

    require(["dojo/_base/array","dojo/store/Memory","dijit/registry","dojo/domReady!"], function(array,Memory,registry){        
    if (!features[0]) {
        alert(noDataFound);
    }
    else {
        array.forEach(features, function(feature, i){
            adress = feature.attributes.STRASSE;

            if (!testVals[adress]) {
                testVals[adress] = true;
                values.push({
                    name: adress
                });
            }

        });
        values.sort(SortByName);

        var dataItems = {
            identifier: 'name',
            label: 'name',
            items: values
        };

            storeStreet = new Memory({
                data: dataItems
            });

 //fill existing Combobox ID,NAME,VALUE,SEARCHATTR,ONCHANGE,STORENAME,COMBOBOX  

        fillExistingCombobox(
            "adrSearchSelectCB",
            "adrSearchSelectCBName",
            "",
            "name",
            getAdresses,
            storeStreet,
            registry.byId("adrSearchSelectCBId")
        );              
    }
});
}

function SortByName(x,y) { 
return ((x.name == y.name) ? 0 : ((x.name > y.name) ? 1 : -1 ));    
}
```

Maybe this brings some Ideas to you how to solve your Question.

Regards, Miriam